# What is a CustomModifier?

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm experimenting with [C# source generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) and I see references to `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CustomModifier` in several places. For example, `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IMethodSymbol` has a property `RefCustomModifiers`.
The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.custommodifier?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.11.0) isn't particularly helpful, and searching the web hasn't turned up anything useful, either.

What C# feature (if any) is represented by a `CustomModifier`?

Comment: Not directly exposed in C#, the compiler generates them as needed to pass options to the just-in-time compiler.  Read [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf), chapter II.7.1.1

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to answer this myself to make it a little easier for someone searching for the same information.

As @HansPassant noted, custom modifiers are addressed by the CLI spec. Some highlights from the noted section:

> **II.7.1.1 modreq and modopt**
> Custom modifiers, defined using modreq
> (“required modifier”) and modopt (“optional modifier”),  are similar
> to custom attributes (§II.21) except that modifiers are part of a
> signature rather than being attached to a declaration.  Each modifer
> associates a type reference with an item in the signature.
>
> [snip]
>
> For example, the const qualifier in the C programming language can be
> modelled with an optional modifier since the caller of a method that
> has a const-qualified parameter need not treat it in any special way.
> On the other hand, a parameter that shall be copy-constructed in C++
> shall be marked with a required custom attribute since it is the
> caller who makes the copy.